# Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed

Tags: sql, insert, dbnull, varbinarymax

I get this exception when I try to insert a DBNull.Value into a **nullable** varbinary(max) field:

> Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

This is my code:

```cs
insertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ErrorScreenshot", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

I know there exist duplicate questions on SO, but I do NOT use any String like the others do.

What do I wrong?

UPDATE:

```
using (var insertCMD = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TestplanTeststep (TeststepId,TestplanId,CreatedAt,ErrorText,ErrorScreenshot,TestState) VALUES (@TeststepId, @TestplanId,@CreatedAt,@ErrorText,@ErrorScreenshot,@TestState)", con))
{
 var p1 = insertCMD.Parameters.Add("@TeststepId", SqlDbType.Int);
 var p2 = insertCMD.Parameters.Add("@CreatedAt", SqlDbType.DateTime);
 insertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestplanId", testplan.Id);
 insertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ErrorText", (object) DBNull.Value);
 insertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ErrorScreenshot", (object) DBNull.Value);
 insertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestState", (int)Teststep.TeststepTestState.Untested);
        
       foreach (Teststep step in teststeps)
        {
           p1.Value = step.Id;
           p2.Value = step.CreatedAt;
           insertCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
     }
```

Comment: Doesn't look like the right line of code. UniqueIdentifier is not mentioned at all. Maybe provide the stored procedure definition too?

Comment: Sorry I copied wrong exception. Now its corrected.

Comment: The second parameter of `AddWithValue` is the value. Not the datatype.

Comment: This bug seems to have returned in .NET5+. The -1 size trick no longer works. Anyone know any other solutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not change your SQL to:

```
INSERT INTO TestplanTeststep
(TeststepId,TestplanId,CreatedAt,ErrorText,ErrorScreenshot,TestState) 
VALUES 
(@TeststepId, @TestplanId,@CreatedAt,NULL,NULL,@TestState)
```

or just

```
INSERT INTO TestplanTeststep
(TeststepId,TestplanId,CreatedAt,TestState) 
VALUES 
(@TeststepId, @TestplanId,@CreatedAt,@TestState)
```

...and omit the two parameters?

If it's always NULL, that will have the same effect.

Otherwise, try it in two lines:

```
var binary1 = insertCMD.Parameters.Add("@ErrorScreenshot", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);
binary1.Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Otherwise, in your original SQL insert statement, you're not defining the parameter type but passing in varbinary, hence the error.

Comment: ah you were faster just found the -1 trick hehe. I want to explicitly set to null this way others or I know about the default behavior of the table.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem while insertion `DBNull.Value` for a `Varbinary(Max)` column. After Googling I found a solution that may help you as well:

You need to set size **-1** which means `Max` length for varbinary column when adding your sql parameter:

```
this.cmd.Parameters.Add("@Photo", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

So in your case:

```
insertCMD.Parameters.Add("@ErrorScreenshot", SqlDbType.VarBinary,-1).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: This basically worked for me. Thank you! I had to make a couple changes so it looks like this: _params.Add("Value", reportCache.Value, DbType.Binary, ParameterDirection.Input, - 1);

Comment: Thank you! that did it.  I was at a loss why it was giving this error.

Comment: This bug seems to have returned in .NET5+. The -1 size trick no longer works. Anyone know any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was resolved using Abdülkadir MAVİ's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72154228/1390170).

I used the line below instead of DBNull.Value:

```
param.Value = Thumbnail is null ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary.Null : Thumbnail;
```